# How to properly code conditional questions in a survey

Tags: r, na, survey

I have this example dataset that includes the following questions :

> Q1 Are you happy ? 1 yes - 0 No
>
> Q2 Why are you happy ? multiple choices questions that you have the data of people who responded positively to the previous questions
>
> Q3 Are you angry ? 1 yes - 0 No
>
> Q4 Why are you angry ? a question conditional on the previous one

```
questions = data.frame(subjects = 1:12,
                       Are_you_happy = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                       why_are_you_happy = 
                         c("1,2,5",NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,"1,3",2,2,NA,NA),
                       Are_you_angry = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                       why_are_you_angry = 
                         c(NA,NA,"1,2,3",6,1,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

I would like your help to find a way to code this dataframe in a way that there is no NAs, and at the same time to take into account the subjects that may check multiple choices (such as subject 1 and 2) for the second and the fourth question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After exchanging opinions, I think a proper way is to code NAs as zeros since they did not respond to the survey questions. And zeros will be leveled as no-response.